# How to mimic tab onAction attribute?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, ribbon

I need to activate a specific Sheet if corresponding tab is activated
XML

```
<tab id="books" label="books" onAction = "goTo1">
```

VBA

```
Sub goTo1()
Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

It seems onAction attribute for tab element doesn't exist (noComment)
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be using the Ribbon Interface "the other way round" - its not possible out of the box. The Idea of the ribbons is, that only actions and tabs are visible that make sense in the current sheet.

What you can do is have a timer on a hidden form that checks the active ribbon and activates the appropriate sheet. Getting the active tab is not trivial though - Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11140486/783388) for details.

Comment: Thanks, Johanness. Your link is helpfull.