# Calling a Macro when a Tab is Clicked

Tags: xml, excel, ribbon, vba

I am using the following piece of XML code to create a custom Ribbon for an Excel add-in.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="ComdinheiroTab" label="COMDINHEIRO">
                <group id="ComdinheiroButtons" label="Comdinheiro">

                    <button id="ButtonTool1" label="Tool1" image="Tool1" size="large" onAction="OnActionTool1"/>

                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I can easily call a macro when a tab's button is pressed with the attribute **onAction**. However I can't do the same with the tab, adding the attribute **onAction** in the tab tag doesn't work. So I ask, is it possible to call a Macro when my tab is clicked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685104/how-to-mimic-tab-onaction-attribute

Comment: From a UI/UX perspective - why would you want to do this? That's what the buttons are for?

Comment: To force the user to login before using my add-in's tools.

Comment: I have the same need but want to set a polling timer when my custom tab is active and disable it when it's not active.