# How to make Access Ribbon Menu 'Sticky'?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have developed an Access ribbon menu and it works.

My question is how to make it 'Sticky?' (tab with selected option remains open)

I.e., let's say you select an option from the 3rd tab of the ribbon. After the process executes, in my application, it throws you back to the first tab on the menu.

If the user selects a menu item from the third tab, I would like the third tab to be visible after the process executes.

I know it is possible since all of MS' default ribbon menus work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in Access 2010 after SP1 (it used to work properly before).

There are some ways to mitigate the issue, but so far no official fix (I have not tested Access 2013 though).

See the question: [Is it possible to prevent MS Access from changing the selected ribbon tab automatically when using a custom ribbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091025/is-it-possible-to-prevent-ms-access-from-changing-the-selected-ribbon-tab-automa)